# What is the purpose of a D Flip-Flop in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Based on the design of the circuit and on the description, what is its purpose?

It says that it transfers the state of D to Q.  This means it can store one bit.

But what is the purpose of a D Flip-Flop when I can just put a lever on a block? This also can store one bit.

Comment: A D flop transfers D to Q on the rising edge of a clock input, C. In Minecraft? Questionable utility, given other design possibilities for more complex circuits. In digital design, it's an integral part of sequential logic.

Comment: Now you might ask why the design is on the minecraft wiki. The most likely explanation is that some electrical engineering students developed circuits they knew from the real world in Minecraft, and posted their designs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saying that you can replace D Flip-Flops with a lever on a block is a bit naive.  The power of D Flip-Flops becomes apparent when you use many of them, and connect them all to the same clock.  You can't possibly toggle half a dozen levers all at the exact same time, but you can effectively do that with D Flip-Flops.

D Flip-Flops form the basis of shift registers, which in turn are a key component in parallel to serial and serial to parallel converters.  These probably aren't very useful in Minecraft; using only two redstone lines (clock and data) instead of the parallel bus width doesn't make up for the slow speed of the serial line compared to a parallel bus.  At best, we might be able to clock a serial line twice as fast as a parallel line, which is not a high enough speed increase.

However, D Flip-Flops are also commonly used as a buffer for parallel bus inputting to a complicated circuit (although the simpler D Latch is often more appropriate).  A buffer is just a bunch of D Flip-Flops all connected to a parallel bus and the same clock.  The best example I can think of for use in Minecraft would be buffering the input to a binary decoder/encoder circuit, such as a seven segment display circuit.  This use would be of dubious value as well though, as you would typically have a T Flip-Flop counter feeding the circuit, and it's just as easy to add dumb delay (i.e. repeaters) in order to synchronize the counter outputs.  Again, a D Latch (which uses just two repeaters) is more appropriate here than a full flip-flop.

Going back to the shift register example, a full D Flip-Flop implementation usually isn't necessary; using inverted one tick pulses to a D Latch will make it act as a D Flip-Flop.  Knowing this, it should become obvious that a full D Flip-Flop implementation usually isn't required, and a D Latch (plus appropriate pulse limiter circuitry) can be used instead.

From my own personal experience, I tend to use T Flip-Flops (either individually or in a counter chain) and RS-NOR Latches in any circuit I build, and those are the components that I would recommend learning after you know how to build the basic logic gates.  From there, I would recommend learning pulse limiters, pulse extenders, and edge detectors.  That doesn't mean there isn't a place for D Flip-Flops, but their utility is often limited to very complex circuitry where input synchronization is absolutely necessary, or where parallel to serial conversion, or vice-versa, is required.  That simply doesn't come up that often in Minecraft circuits.

Answer (score 0):

DFFs are probably one of the **biggest, *most used*** things in computational redstone, it is the basis for ROM *and* RAM(when paired with a D Latch), allowing you to choose what data you want to read and when, without it, you'd struggle to build many of the impressive redstone builds that mattbatwings, Sloimay, and many others have achieved.

The actual purpose is to only allow the data to be read when you power the C input or clock input. If you stack many 8-bit registers and you attach a decoder to the bottom, depending on which register you decode for, it'll only output *that* register.

Overall, the main utilization isn't for player usage, but more for machine use, the machine can't change the state of a lever, so a DFF it is.